# HTML5 audio not playing on Mobile Chrome (Android)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have an HTML5  element that plays an embedded audio file upon click. This is what the code looks like:

HTML:

```
<span class="sound">
    <audio id="yourAudio" preload="none" onplay="playing(this);" onended="stopped(this);">
        <source src="/sandboxassets/pronunciations/estest106f444b36e7b5fdb88a10706d397dc2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="audioControl" onclick="playclip(this);" title="Hear it spoken">
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-volume-down pronounce"></i>
    </a>
</span>
```

JS:

```
// play pronunciation file
function playclip(mp3){
    mp3.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
    return false; // Prevent Default Action
}
function playing(thisicon){
    // var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("pronounce")[0];
    var icon = thisicon.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('pronounce')[0];
    icon.className = "fa fa-2x fa-volume-up pronounce";
}
function stopped(thisicon){
    // var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("pronounce")[0];
    var icon = thisicon.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('pronounce')[0];
    icon.className = "fa fa-2x fa-volume-down pronounce";
}
```

This setup works perfectly fine in at least desktops browsers: Chrome, Edge, and Opera (yet to test on Safari, IE, and Firefox). However, the click does nothing on Chrome Android. Any idea where I could be going wrong with this? The code is live at www.peppyburro.com/sandboxdictionary/fugar.

A question with the exact same title exists here but the provided solution doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for because I have not explicitly added *.htaccess* password protection on my site.

Comment: Of course it's being called. That's how it's working in desktop browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android and iPhone touch events

> touchstart    ↔ mousedown
>  touchend  ↔ mouseup
>  touchmove   ↔
>   mousemove
>  touchcancel

```
document.getElementById('yourAudio').addEventListener("mouseup", tapOrClick, false);
document.getElementById('yourAudio').addEventListener("touchend", tapOrClick, false);

function tapOrClick(e) {
    var mp3 = e.target;
        mp3.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
}
```